# Azure WebJobs SDK - in what scenarios is creation of a JobHost object required?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Most of the samples associated with the Azure WebJobs SDK have startup code that looks like this:

```csharp
static void Main()
{
    JobHost h = new JobHost();
    h.RunAndBlock();
}
```

However you can also kick off a WebJob without creating a `JobHost` object like this:

```csharp
static void Main()
{
    // Do something...
}
```

In what scenarios is the `JobHost` necessary?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need the Jobs Host Configuration when you want to interact with Azure Storage (table storage, queues, blobs) or ServiceBus **and if you want to expose your functions to the Azure WebJobs Dashboard**.

This is some code I use in a WebJob that doesn't use JobHost

```csharp
static ISubscriptions _subscriptions;

static void Main()
{
    Process();
}

public static void Process()
{
    _subscriptions.DoWork();
}
```

Comment: I also just found that the JobHost configuration is required if you want to expose your methods to the dashboard so you can invoke them.  (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811659/can-i-create-an-azure-webjob-that-exposes-functions-to-the-dashboard-but-doesnt).  Just a suggestion: you might want to simplify your example to remove the first 3 lines under Main() because to someone new to Webjobs it might appear that your code is somehow Webjobs specific.  Meaning, that you could significantly generalize & simplify your code example by simply only having Process() in Main.

Comment: Also, if you update your answer to include the part about requiring a JobHost if you want to expose your methods to the dashboard for invocation, I will mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 21):

WebJobs and WebJobs SDK are two different things even though their name is similar.

- The WebJobs (without SDK) is a feature of Azure Websites. It is a generic, language/platform agnostic engine that can execute jobs. You can write jobs in many languages including: node, batch, C#/VB/any other .NET language
- The WebJobs SDK is a framework, only for .NET, that simplifies the task of writing code that works with Azure Storage queues, blobs, and tables, and Service Bus queues; also, it is not tied to the WebJobs feature of Web Sites - it can run in any .NET application.

The `JobHost` is the entry point for the Azure WebJobs SDK. It is responsible for indexing, publishing, monitoring and scheduling the functions defined using WebJobs SDK artifacts. Whenever you want to invoke a WebJobs SDK function (triggered or manual/called) you need an instance of the `JobHost`. If your code doesn't require Azure Storage/ServiceBus or if you want to write all the polling/logging yourself, you don't need the Azure WebJobs SDK.

Comment: <<  If your code doesn't require Azure Storage/ServiceBus or if you want to write all the polling/logging yourself, you don't need the Azure WebJobs SDK. >> ...or if you want your methods to show up in the function dashboard.