# Expose webjobs functions to dashboard without azure storage

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811659/can-i-create-an-azure-webjob-that-exposes-functions-to-the-dashboard-but-doesnt) there's an example on how to use a webjob that can perform some background operations without interacting with azure table storage.

I tried to replicate the code in the answer but it's throwing the following error:

*' 'Void ScheduleNotifications()' can't be invoked from Azure WebJobs SDK. Is it missing Azure WebJobs SDK attributes? '*

In [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-US/6d66b261-535d-4b0e-9a0f-b9cf6db832a1/missing-azure-webjobs-sdk-attributes?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) they have a similar error and in one of the answers it says that this was fixed in the 0.4.1-beta release. I'm running the 0.5.0-beta release and I'm experiencing the error.

Here's a copy of my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var config = new JobHostConfiguration(AzureStorageAccount.ConnectionString);
        var host = new JobHost(config);

        host.Call(typeof(Program).GetMethod("ScheduleNotifications"));

        host.RunAndBlock();
    }

    [NoAutomaticTrigger]
    public static void ScheduleNotifications()
    {
        //Do work
    }
}
```

I want to know if I'm missing something or is this still a bug in the Webjobs SDK.

Update: Per Victor's answer, the Program class has to be public.

Working code:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var config = new JobHostConfiguration(AzureStorageAccount.ConnectionString);
        var host = new JobHost(config);

        host.Call(typeof(Program).GetMethod("ScheduleNotifications"));

        host.RunAndBlock();
    }

    [NoAutomaticTrigger]
    public static void ScheduleNotifications()
    {
        //Do work
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unless you use a custom type locator, a function has to satisfy all conditions below:

- it has to be public
- it has to be static
- it has to be non abstract
- it has to be in a non abstract class
- it has to be in a public class

Your function doesn't meet the last condition. If you make the class public it will work.

Also, if you use webjobs sdk 0.5.0-beta and you run a program with only the code in your example, you will see a message saying that no functions were found.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll make the appropriate changes and redeploy. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the help Victor. This solved the problem. I also updated to 0.6.0 beta and the got the error you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Came looking for an answer here, but didn't quite find it in the answer above, though everything he said is true. My problem was that I accidentally changed the inbound property names of a Azure web job so that they DIDN'T match the attributes of the object the function was supposed to catch. Duh!

For the concrete example:

my web job was listening for a queue message based on this class:

```
public class ProcessFileArgs
{
    public ProcessFileArgs();

    public string DealId { get; set; }
    public ProcessFileType DmsFileType { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
}
```

But my public static async class in the Functions.cs file contained this as a function definition, where the declared parameters didn't match the names within the queue message class for which it was waiting:

```
    public static async Task LogAndLoadFile(
        [QueueTrigger(Queues.SomeQueueName)] ProcessFileArgs processFileArgs,
        string dealid,
        string emailaddress,
        string file,            
        [Blob("{fileFolder}/{Filename}", FileAccess.Read)] Stream input,
        TextWriter log,
        CancellationToken cancellationToke)
    {
```

So if you run into this problem, check to make sure the parameter and attribute names match.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you have the arguments in the class and also declared separately?

Comment: They're in separate projects. The ProcessFileArgs class, one of many, is declared in a regular dll project that's reference by the web jobs that way multiple web jobs can send each other queue messages. The usual - abstraction.