# Azure WebJob Function had errors

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have an Azure WebJob and when it picks up a message from the queue I get the error

"Function had errors. See Azure WebJobs SDK dashboard for details".

The dashboard shows no errors, it just insists my connection strings are not set which they are or else it wouldn't pick up the message.

When debugging locally how can I find out what the actual error is?

Comment: Your connection string that's set locally should also be added to the Azure Website in which the Webjob resides through the portal. You should add Azure storage connection strings with the appropriate names to get functions exposed to the dashboard. Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811659/can-i-create-an-azure-webjob-that-exposes-functions-to-the-dashboard-but-doesnt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can debug locally by explicitly setting the Dashboard connection string to null in the JobHostConfiguration object. That will make the host show all errors in the console rather than dashboard.

What connection strings do you set (their names)?

Comment: Can you give an example of how to do this?  I'm trying to do it but I must not be doing it in the right place as I keep getting errors.